# Eigenvectors for eigenvalues in algebraic closure

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory

For a matrix $A$ acting on a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over arbitrary field $F$, by considering the characteristic polynomial, we can find its eigenvectors $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\bar{F}$ ($F$'s algebraic closure). Do these correspond to vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\bar{F}\otimes_FV$ for which $Av_i=\lambda v_i$?

Comment: If you view everything in terms of $\bar{F}$ then yes each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ can be associated with eigenvectors, namely elements of $\ker (A - \lambda_i I)$.

Comment: More is true: the coefficients of the eigenvector $v_i$ can be chosen to lie in $F[\lambda_i]$.